# the equation $a^x+(a+1)^y=(a+2)^z$ in natural numbers.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Fermat's Last Theorem for consecutive numbers, i.e. the equation $a^n+(a+1)^n=(a+2)^n$ in natural numbers, is a well-known problem at olympiad level (it can be shown without any eliptic curves and other advanced stuff, that there are no solutions for $n\ge 3$).

Let's consider the very natural generalisation - the equation $a^x+(a+1)^y=(a+2)^z$.

I guessed the following solutions: $(a,x,y,z)$ being one of $(1,X,1,1),(1,X,3,2),(3,2,2,2)$, where $X$ can be any natural number.

Are there any others?

Can it be solved with stuff like binomial formula, modular arithmetic, estimations (olympiad level solution; these methods are sufficient to solve the mentioned case of Fermat's equation)?

Comment: Unless I am missing something obvious, it will be much harder to prove that the generalization has no solutions

Comment: Clearly, $gcd(a,a+1,a+2)=1$, so when $x>2$, $y>2$ and $z>2$ this is a subset of equations covered by The Beal Conjecture http://www.bealconjecture.com/